# Loop thru array of dictionary and add new key to each dictionary in iOS

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I found something strange today in iOS, I solved it, but I would like to ask is there better (more iOS) solution.

What I wanted to do is:
Loop thru array of dictionary and add new key to each dictionary in iOS

This is code (this is not my original code, it is more complicated, but I done this code for illustrating the point easy):

```
- (void)testLoopThruArrayOfDictionaryAndAddNewKeyToEachDictionary
{
    NSMutableArray* a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [a addObjectsFromArray:@[ @{@"one": @11, @"two": @12, } ]];
    [a addObjectsFromArray:@[ @{@"one": @21, @"two": @22, } ]];

    NSLog(@"%@", a);

    /*
    // NOT WORKING
    for (NSMutableDictionary* dict in a)
    {
        // -[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8b5bca0
        [dict setObject:@3 forKey:@"three"]; 
    }
    */

    // THIS IS WORKING
    for (int i=0; i<[a count]; i++)
    {
        // make tmp copy
        NSMutableDictionary *tmpA = [a[i] mutableCopy];

        [tmpA setObject:@3 forKey:@"three"];

        // put to new value, because I use this [allValidMoves[i] mutableCopy];
        a[i] = tmpA;
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", a);
}
```

As you can see second loop is working, but I need to make copy of array and then put that copy back to array.
First loop was returning NSDictionary even when I asked for NSMutableDictionary.

**QUESTION**
1. Is it possible to do this with less code ?
2. Are there some side effect to my implementation ?

Comment: it does not matter how you cast a class – like `NSMutableDictionary` in your first case – because you have created _immutable_ `NSDictionary` objects in your array basically. a simple typecasting does not change the type of the original object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First ensure the array holds `NSMutableDictionary` objects, and not `NSDictionary` objects to avoid the need to convert while iterating:

<strike>NSMutableArray* a = [ @[
        [ @{@"one": @11, @"two": @12, } mutableCopy],
        [ @{@"one": @21, @"two": @22, } mutableCopy]
    ] mutableCopy ];</strike>

(I don't like that code, use this instead):

```
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray new];
[a addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@(11), @"one", @(12), @"two", nil]];
[a addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@(21), @"one", @(22), @"two", nil]];
```

And then use:

```
[a enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = (NSMutableDictionary *)obj;
    dict[@"three"] = @(3);
}];
```

Comment: by now that makes zero sense why you created a mutable copy of an already mutable array, I was going to correct that, but you are so keen to keep that nonsense.

Comment: @holex Because Objective-C literals are immutable, not mutable.

Comment: oh, I see now. you just highlighted the main reason why I'm not using those crazy literals at all.

Comment: @holex Well they are extremely useful in making the code more readable in cases where immutable objects are required, however I dislike the need for `mutableCopy` in the code of my answer and would probably re-write it to use more conventional `alloc/init` methods if this was actually my code.

Comment: yes, but here, you are just wasting re-sources with first creating an _immutable_ object then copy them as _mutable_ one.

Comment: lol, that is not less readable, mate – but just the opposite. :)

Comment: Seriously?  With the keys and values reversed and the need for `nil` and `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:`?  I disagree, but it's not important.

Comment: I don't know why, I'm not a Apple engineer... but on based of syntax many solutions can be questioned because from a particular view those'd make any sense – but pointless doing such thing. I highlighted only the wasted resources here.

Comment: @trojanfoe you did nice explaining what is the problem and I understand it. I have one issue hot to use `mutableCopy` with `addObjectsFromArray` this is code where I add dictionary `[possibleMoves addObjectsFromArray: @[ @{@"take": cardsOnTable, @"with": takingCardView} ] ];`so far I have not fount the way to add `mutableCopy` to it.

Comment: @WebOrCode Yeah I have reverted to using the class methods rather than the compiler-supported literal syntax to make it clearer and I don't think mixing them is very readable.